# Answer deleted by moderator from a question that I flagged as a duplicate a year ago, because the answer was a duplicate and the question was not?

Tags: discussion, support

**This question is not a duplicate and has no duplicates on the sites, or any sites, or the whole internets**.

Why did this answer get removed by a moderator

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54335563/124486

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Instead, tailor the answer to the question asked. If the questions are exact duplicates of each other, please vote/flag to close instead. – Samuel Liew♦ 3 mins ago

What answer is he alleging that it's a duplicate of? I always flag questions as a duplicate when I think that they're duplicates.

My guess is he's calling that answer a duplicate of an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751520/how-to-generate-sequence-of-numbers-chars-in-javascript/54335525#comment85432942_3751520). That question though I flagged as a Dupe on March 18, of 2018 -- almost a full year ago. You can see that here,

> [How to generate sequence of numbers/chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751520/how-to-generate-sequence-of-numbers-chars-in-javascript/54335525#comment85432942_3751520)

Others decided that this question was **not** a duplicate. So I answered both of them because I think my answer is better than the answers on both of them. What's wrong with that? My answers functions for both of those questions. If both questions are thought not to be a dupe -- why can't I answer them both with the same content if I believe it answers both questions, better? If one of the answers has to be deleted. But as far as mod-action, wouldn't it have been a better idea to delete the answer on the less-popular question?

[image]

One of those questions is

> [Does JavaScript have a method like “range()” to generate a range within the supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3895478/124486)

The answer is that you have to create it, I explain how.

> [How to generate sequence of numbers/chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3751520/124486)

The answer is you have to create it, I explain how.

I'm not sure how they're different -- that's why I flagged them as duplicates. What kind of customization is required here?

In my answer I explain how to create both an iterator, and an array. I include extra functionality like a `step` argument too. It goes above and beyond to answer both with es6 regardless of the definition of "range" and "sequence" which isn't present in either question.

Comment: "So I answered both of them because I think my answer is better than the answers on both of them. What's wrong with that?" The mod's message doesn't say anything is wrong with answering both questions, it just requests, seeing that you copy and pasted **exactly** the same answer, "Instead, tailor the answer to the question asked."

Comment: there is no tailoring possible.I will explain.

Comment: The same answer can be applicable to multiple questions without being a duplicate. A question is only a duplicate if all possible answers to the question are also possible answers to the target and vice versa.

Comment: @TinyGiant that sounds like you're consenting to my answer which I believe is applicable to both questions which I personally believe are duplicates, but that I may not be in the majority in seeing the questions like that. How am I going to deduplicate my question if I honestly think it answers two questions that I feel *are* duplicates?

Comment: If you feel the questions are in-fact duplicates then posting the answer to both would be wrong. If you think the questions are not duplicates but the answer applies to both, that would be different.

Answer (score 25):

Since you believe the questions are duplicates, vote to close accordingly.  Post your answer on the canonical version of the question, if you feel that it's better than the existing solutions.

That other people haven't agreed with you and voted to close the question doesn't make it okay for you to copy-paste your answer to questions that you think are duplicates.

Comment: Why? I believe my answer answers both questions? If you don't shouldn't you be downvoting on the question you feel it doesn't answer?  Or, explain to me what form you want the answer to come in or where you feel my answer is deficient?

Comment: @EvanCarroll I never said that the questions weren't duplicates.  You said that you think they're duplicates, and as such, you should not answer both.

Comment: **WHY**? That doesn't make sense. Where is that a rule anywhere? I think they're duplicates. I want to help everyone. I think the answers on both of them are of bad form and quality and I would like my answer to be considered for the greater good on both of them. If you're convinced they're duplicates -- **join me** in voting to close one. If they both stay open, I think I can make **BOTH** of them better with my contribution. It seems totally arbitrary for you to tell me to withhold my submission on one, as if I'm plagiarizing myself or doing something wrong.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Why do you think it *does* make sense to have people going around re-posting the exact same answers on every version of a duplicate question?  You already have the means to point people to the answer you think is best, voting to close.  That others haven't doesn't change what the correct course of action is.  You *are* doing something wrong by going around reposting the same answer.

Comment: I did vote to close. I'm not arguing that both should stay open. The moderators have to pick a position. Mine is (a) they're duplicates, (b) my answer is the best to **both** forms of the same question. If you believe they're **not** duplicates, then explain to me why my answer doesn't fit both. If my specific answer fits both questions you feel are not duplicates, and answers both better than all other answers it doesn't make sense to me why I should remove one of them.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Once again, I never said that the questions weren't duplicates.  You think they are, you've cast your vote, it's not appropriate to copy the answer.

Comment: *"It's not appropriate to copy the answer"* You're not making an argument here, let's be clear you haven't answered *why* once. Ok, so you feel that way and you argue by fiat. Great contribution to the conversation.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Like, the whole point of closing questions as duplicates is so that people don't do exactly what you did: duplicate the answers. We want the answer in one place, because that is how a properly constructed knowledge base would work. Or to put it another way, we close questions to keep people from answering them. If two questions are duplicates, then that means one of them should be closed as a dupe of the other. And therefore, you should not answer one of them. It's no different from answering a question about finding a library.

Comment: There's two reasons why answers should not be carbon-copied. Firstly, they do not stay in sync - improvements to one are nearly never copied to the other versions. Secondly, if we allow it, it becomes a cheap way to rep-farm - answer once and then spam the site with other copies. We've had this rule for some years.